# How To Hide Certain Text With CSS?

Tags: html, css

A friend helped me set my WordPress website about Basketball shoes. I've published a few posts. However, there is the date just below the Title!

Example:

```
Best Basketball Shoes 2021 – Top 10 Basketball Shoes To Have In 2021
NOVEMBER 13, 2020 By IAN DANIEL
```

See here: https://basketballonpoint.com/best-basketball-shoes/

How can I hide the date via CSS? It's 2021 now!

Comment: ? I assume November 13, 2020 is the publication date(?) The publication date doesn't change just because it's 2021 now.  Note that people's answers to display:none in your theme is going to apply to everything, not just that one article.

Comment: @robert-adams This question really requires much more research and study before asking a good question for S.O. The problem needs to be laid out in more detail as well. If you req. code then try to give it a try and describe what went wrong, for example. See this [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following CSS:

```
.entry-meta .entry-time {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put Display:none; to the class/div it is in if you want to hide it with css.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update the CSS for your theme. The rule you need is:

```
p.entry-meta {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: this would hide the whole paragrah: "NOVEMBER 13, 2020 By IAN DANIEL",
instead of just "NOVEMBER 13, 2020" as the OP is requesting.
I don't think he wants to hide the author name also

Comment: @GBra If so, then the selector would be `.entry-meta > time`

Comment: with your answer, you would display none this paragraph (and all of his children)

<p class="entry-meta"><time class="entry-time">November 13, 2020</time> By <span><a><span class="entry-author-name">Ian Daniel</span></a></span> </p>

He only wants to hide this, instead:
<time class="entry-time">November 13, 2020</time>

Comment: @GBra That's incorrect. `.entry-meta > time` would select `<time class="entry-time">November 13, 2020</time>` only. Try it. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/erv8dfta/

Comment: yeah, the ".entry-meta > time" works too, I was just trying to say that your original answer 
(selector "p.entry-meta") hides the whole paragraph. You might want to change to ".entry-meta > time" as you wrote in the comments

Answer (score 0):

```css
.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Best Basketball Shoes 2021 – Top 10 Basketball 
  Shoes To Have In 2021
</h1>

<p class="hide">NOVEMBER 13, 2020 By IAN DANIEL</p>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Perhaps explain why (and how) this works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set display: none to the class of that element.

**To Remove Whole sentance**

```
p.entry-meta {
   display: none;
}
```

**To Remove only the date**

```
.entry-meta time.entry-time {
    display: none;
}
```

For future reference I'll suggest you go over this post to [Learn how to find elements with Google dev tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools)